# Base Web do MySQL em Cache

Tags: mysql, delphi

Bom dia,

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi 2010 com MySQL, a base fica em servidor na Web, há alguns dias migraram esse servidor e atualizaram a versão do MySQL, desde então tenho tido um problema, quando um dos clientes insere uma informação na base ela sobe instantaneamente, porém o outro cliente leva um bom tempo para enxergar o novo registro, é como se o cliente armazenasse um cache da consulta, e esse cache atualizasse a cada tanto tempo, as vezes o outro cliente leva mais de um dia pra enxergar o novo registro, alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo ou de como resolver isso?

Comment: Em condições normais isto não ocorre. Ou é alguma limitação na lógica de consulta da sua aplicação, ou a consulta não está sendo feita diretamente ao MySQL. Eventualmente pode ter sido instalado um MySQL clusterizado e/ou replicado e mal configurado, mas aí só conferindo a instalação propriamente dita (e mesmo assim, o problema só ocorreria se cada cliente conectasse em um ponto diferente do cluster, o que provavelmente não seria o caso).